# JS how to capture logic for field validation based on characters typed then deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form field where feedback is provided to the user filling it out. For example, a length requirement of iMinLength or more characters.

In the beginning of the user typing, I don't want to trigger an error message because they are probably still typing.

How can I only show a length validation message if they have typed the required 6 chars and then deleted some so that the length is now less than 6 chars?

Here is a mock-up of the logic I have, it does everything I need except the part I mentioned above.

How can I adjust it to behave as indicated above? I basically want this part to execute during typing (e.g. `input` is firing) when user had typed 6 or more chars first, then went to less than 6.

`$('#sNewPasswordResult').html('<span style="color:red;">Password must be at least 6 characters</span>');`

Here is the full chunk so far:

```
$(document).on('input blur', '#sSignUpPassword', function (e) {

if ($('#sSignUpPassword').val().length > iMinLength) {

    $('#sNewPasswordResult').html("Password: <i class='fa fa-fw fa-check' style='color:#339933'>");
    $('#sSignUpPassword').css("border", "1px solid green");
}
else {      
    if (e.type == 'focusout') { //only for leaving the form field

        $('#sNewPasswordResult').html('<span style="color:red;">Password must be at least 6 characters</span>');
        $('#sSignUpPassword').css("border", "1px solid red");
    }

};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem by creating a flag to control if the user reaches the minimum characters, then I show the error if the user delete chars until the minimum, like this:

```
  $("#passwd").keyup(function() {
    var $passwd = $(this);

    if ($passwd.val().length >= 6) {
      $passwd.data("reach-typing", true);
    }
  });
  $("#passwd").blur(function() {
    var $passwd = $(this);

    if ($passwd.val().length < 6 && $passwd.data("reach-typing") === true) {
      $("#errorLength").show();
    } else {
      $("#errorLength").hide();
    }
  });
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zt9HLg?p=preview